# Defining a controller in a $routeProvider route that is located in a separate file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The original code is as follows:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('test', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/test', {
                    templateUrl: '/templates/test.html',
                    controller: 'testCtrl'
                })
                .when('/test2', {
                    templateUrl: '/templates/test2.html',
                    controller: 'test2Ctrl'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/test'
                });
        });
})();

//ANOTHER FILE
(function() {
    angular.module('test')
        .controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.name = "test";
        })
        .controller('test2Ctrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.name = "test2";
        });
});
```

There were no errors, but all that would show up in the templates was `{{name}}` instead of what was defined in the scope.

Then I tried moving the controllers into another module and dependency injected it in. Interestingly, even if the controllers were moved to a separate module it would not work:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('test2', []);
    angular.module('test', ['ngRoute', 'test2']);
})();

//ANOTHER FILE
(function() {
    angular.module('test')
        .config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/test', {
                    templateUrl: '/templates/test.html',
                    controller: 'testCtrl'
                })
                .when('/test2', {
                    templateUrl: '/templates/test2.html',
                    controller: 'test2Ctrl'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/test'
                });
        });
})();

//ANOTHER FILE
(function() {
    angular.module('test2')
        .controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.name = "test";
        })
        .controller('test2Ctrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.name = "test2";
        });
});
```

In fact, in this one it threw an error that the controllers could not be found.

From my understanding this is happening because due to the nature of how the config block runs, and how it runs before the controllers have been registered.

One way I've solved this is by instead moving the controller and template into a directive and then using the directive itself as the template.

```
(function() {
    angular.module('test')
        .config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    template: '<test></test>'
                })
                .when('/test2', {
                    template: '<test2></test2>'
                })
                .when('/test3', {
                    template: '<test3></test3>'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        });
})();
```

I was wondering if anyone else had a way to support putting controllers into a router when your controllers are in a separate file.

Comment: code looks good should work..are you getting any error?

Comment: @pankajparkar I know right?? Turns out if you remove the self invoking anonymous function around the controllers it works fine, but that doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: let me look at it by setting up plunkr..or why you don't reproduce same problem with plunkr

Comment: @pankajparkar [it works in plunker, but not online...](http://plnkr.co/edit/byPTxZKLFE8jaX1n1U86)

Comment: @pankajparkar I figured it out. Thanks for telling me to put it on plunkr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been missing an `()` self executing function (IIFE) on the file of your controller.

```
//ANOTHER FILE
(function() {
    angular.module('test2')
        .controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.name = "test";
        })
        .controller('test2Ctrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.name = "test2";
        });
})(); //<-- added here
```

Comment: I just figured it out as well! I will accept your answer, however, because you telling me to put it on plunkr solved my problem.

Comment: @AR7 really I wasted my time to adding answer..should have commented first..actually I wanted to give surprise to you..but you did it first..:p Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can organize the project in this way

```
templates/
    test.html
    test2.html
app/
    app.js
    controllers/
        testCtrl.js
        test2Ctrl.js
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {
    angular.module('test', ['ngRoute'])
        .config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/test', {
                    templateUrl: '/templates/test.html',
                    controller: 'testCtrl'
                })
                .when('/test2', {
                    templateUrl: '/templates/test2.html',
                    controller: 'test2Ctrl'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/test'
                });
        });
})();
```

**html files**

Once you add the controllers in your html file may no longer have the problem

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
    <body ng-controller='TextController'>
    ....
    ....
    ....
    <script src="app/controllers/testCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/test2Ctrl.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code here was missing the `()` that would execute it...

```
(function() {
    angular.module('test')
        .controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.name = "test";
        })
        .controller('test2Ctrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.name = "test2";
        });
});
```

Should be:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('test')
        .controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.name = "test";
        })
        .controller('test2Ctrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.name = "test2";
        });
})();
```

Comment: Glad to help you..Thanks for appreciation:)